# Why is percona xtrabackup so slow and big

Tags: mysql, percona, mysql-backup

When I call innobackupex with no arguments, it produces a backup of all databases. It takes three minutes, and produces an 8gb output. When I run mysqldump --all-databases, it takes 1 minutes, and produces a 1.5gb output. Since both of these outputs can be used to recreate the same database, why is xtrabackup so much slower and larger?

Answer (score 3):

Is your ibdata1 file 8gb?  xtrabackup does a hot copy of the entire file.  The hot copy process doesn't need to lock tables (which allows your database to be available during the backup process).  The disadvantage is that unused space in your file is also backed up.